# I want to make a rails model but I don't want to store it in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make an object that will handle all facebook-related issues. For example, I want to say object.is_access_token_valid? or object.get_user_email or object.authenticate_user. There is a lot of complex functionality I want to package in this one object and I want to abstract this from the user of the object. In java, this would be an object. What would this be in ruby/rails?

Here's my specific situation:

I am getting this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table

Here is my code:

```
class FacebookSession < ActiveRecord::Base

#include OauthHelper

  attr_accessor :fb_token, :fb_client, :fb_user_id, :fb_email

  def initialize
    @fb_client = client # makes new oauth client
    @fb_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new client, fb_token
  end

  def get_email
    self.fb_token.get('/me/interests')
  end

  def get_fb_user_id
    self.fb_token.get('/me/interests')
  end

  def authenticate
    #if this fb_user_id is in the database, log them in otherwise don't
  end

  def is_valid?
    if(try_access_token(self.access_token))
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't extend from `ActiveRecord::Base` on the first line, you can get a plain-jane class, which you can use to hold any logic you want.

```
class FacebookSession
  attr_accessor :fb_token, :fb_client, :fb_user_id, :fb_email

  def initialize(client, fb_token)
    @fb_client = client # makes new oauth client
    @fb_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new client, fb_token
  end

  def get_interests
    @fb_token.get('/me/interests')
  end

  # etc    
end

# somewhere else

session = FacebookSession.new(client, token)
email = session.get_interests
```

Comment: Perfect. This is obvious when you step back a second! Thank you!